# FFmpeg concat and then add soundtrack results in a soundtrack that stutters

Tags: ffmpeg, synchronization, concatenation

I am trying to create a video composed of clips of images and videos.  For the clips of images, I use ffmpeg to create a video file and then I add a silent audio stream through these two steps:

```
ffmpeg.exe -loop 1 -i MyImage.png -codec:v libx264 -t 4.0 -profile:v high -preset slow -r 25 -b:v 500k -maxrate 500k -pix_fmt yuv420p -vf scale=1280:720 MyImageMovie.mp4

ffmpeg.exe -f lavfi -i anullsrc=r=48000 -i MyImageMovie.mp4 -shortest -c:v copy -c:a aac -strict experimental -y MyImageMovieWithSilentAudioStream.mp4
```

Then I combine my video clips and image clips with

```
ffmpeg.exe -f concat -i videoList.txt -c copy -y concatVideo.mp4
```

At this point, the video looks good, any video clips that have audio streams seemed well synced to the video.

Now I add a soundtrack:

```
ffmpeg.exe -i concatVideo.mp4 -i soundtrack.mp3 -ar 48000 -filter_complex "[1:a]apad [b] ; [0:a][b]amerge=inputs=2[a]" -map 0:v -map "[a]" -c:v copy -ac 2 -shortest -y FinalVideo.mp4
```

The problem is that the soundtrack on `FinalVideo.mp4` stutters at some (not all) of the concatenation joints.

I suspect it has to do with the audio stream and the video stream of the Image clips not being perfectly aligned.  The aac has .0231s resolution and the video has 0.04s resolution.  When I ffprobe the `MyImageMovieWithSilentAudioStream.mp4` the duration is 4.00s but the start is 0.0213.

If my concatenated video has several of these image clips, the error can start to accumulate.

What can I do to keep the video and audio in sync and add a soundtrack that doesn't stutter?

Also, this is a little interesting, I don't hear the stutter when the final video is played on Windows Media Player, but it is there if I play it on VLC or via the html native video element.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the soundtrack in the same step as the concat.

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i videoList.txt -i soundtrack.mp3 \
-filter_complex "[1:a]apad[b];[0:a][b]amerge=inputs=2[a]" \
-map 0:v -map "[a]"
-c:v copy -c:a aac -ac 2 -ar 48000 -shortest -y FinalVideo.mp4
```

---

As an aside, you can also combine the image and silent stream generation,

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i MyImage.png -f lavfi -i anullsrc=r=48000 \
-vf scale=1280:720 \
-c:v libx264 -profile:v high -preset slow -r 25 -b:v 500k -maxrate 500k -pix_fmt yuv420p \
-c:a aac -strict experimental -t 4 -y MyImageMovieWithSilentAudioStream.mp4
```

Comment: I gave this a try and I still get the audio stutters when I play it through VLC.    I appreciate the idea, though.

Comment: Run my command with `-vn` added and play the output in VLC and check. This will be an audio-only file.